# Options wont load in select component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

`Multiselect(:options="passwordTypes")`

I got this function

```js
    const passwordTypes = async () => {
      await PASSWORD_TYPES.map(type => {
        return { 
          label: t(`passwordType.${type.value}`),
          value: type.value
        }
      });
    }
```

It wont load at all my password types, when I console.log(passwordTypes()) it returns an array of 15 items, so why it isn't loading it in my html?

Can someone tell me how can I push these items to my Multiselect component?

Comment: I highly doubt `PASSWORD_TYPES.map` returns a Promise - so why are you awaiting it?

Comment: I doubt the `Multiselect` component options accept a promise.

Comment: Because I get this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` If I dont